# asp.net multivew control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Set active view control using name with string name asp.net 4.0 
e.g

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
        <asp:View runat="server" ID="first">
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View runat="server" ID="second">
        </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Now want to active on button click as like

```
string viewname=first;
MultiView1.SetActiveView(view: viewname);
```

This is not working here is another way to acitve view as like this

```
MultiView1.SetActiveView(view: first);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`MultiView.SetActiveView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.setactiveview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method sets the specified [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.view_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) control to be the active one, In the code behind all the views defined in your multiview control such as `first`, `second` are listed by the IntelliSense for the views to be passed to this method:

[image: see this image]

so all you need is pass the view's `ID` defined in your multiview control like this:

```
MultiView1.SetActiveView(first);
```